# How to sum over a two tensor with a simple constraint of the form $i<j$?

Tags: summation, tensors

I am trying to write a sum of the form
$$\sum_{i<j}f_{ij}$$
where $i,j\in \{1,2,3,4\}.$

I want to write something like `Sum[f[[i,j]], {j,1,4},{i,1,j}]`
but then this is equal to the following sum
$$\sum_{i\leq j}f_{ij}.$$

I know that I can subtract the $f_{ii}$ from this and recover the answer, but the quantities that I am summing over involve several metrics and tensors so I was wondering if there is a clean way to write sums like I mentioned earlier?

Comment: ```Sum[f[[i,j]], {j,1,4},{i,1,j-1}]```?

Comment: I thought about that too, but does mathematica know how to deal with the case j=1 ?

Comment: If you're worried about that, you could always use `Sum[f[[i,j]], {j,2,4},{i,1,j-1}]` instead.

Comment: @ShreyAryan Yes. Mathematica follows the common convention that if the upper bound is smaller than the lower bound, then ```Sum``` returns ```0```. ```Table``` and ```Product``` behave similarly, returning ```{}``` and ```1``` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
Sum[Boole[i < j] f[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

> `f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[1, 4] + f[2, 3] + f[2, 4] + f[3, 4]`

Comment: thanks again :)

Comment: you're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
Plus @@ (Subsets[Range[4], {2}] /. {i_, j_} -> f[i, j])
```

> `f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[1, 4] + f[2, 3] + f[2, 4] + f[3, 4]`

I missed the following, which is simpler and equivalent to the above. Thanks to the comment by @ AsukaMinato that pointed it out

```
Total @ (Subsets[Range[4], {2}] /. {i_, j_} -> f[i, j])
```

Comment: `Plus @@` kind of equals to `Total@`

Comment: `Subsets[Range[4], {2}] // Map[Apply@f] // Total` also works.

Comment: @AsukaMinato yes, that's also a very nice way to go about it. Although, I do prefer the answer you provided which is much shorter :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way likes @kcr's method.

```
f @@@ Subsets[Range[4], {2}] // Total
```

shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner -and again thanks to @AsukaMinato for the previous comment

```
Total[Normal@
  SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i < j :> f[i, j], {4, 4}], Infinity]
```